# Get items from DataTemplate for ArtOfTest controls

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests, datatemplate

I have this kind of object in code:

```
ArtOfTest.WebAii.Controls.Xaml.Wpf.ListBox
```

Items of it are in ItemTemplate. I have collection of it:

```
var listBoxItems = repairComapanyHintsList.Find.AllByType<ListBoxItem>();
```

and I want to get control from that DataTemplate. How can I do it? That solution doesn't work for DataTemplate (for other situations it's ok):

```
var textBlock = listBoxItem.Find.ByName("Name");
```

How can I get it? I tried this solution too, but that controls (from ArtOfTest) doesn't DependencyObject:
[How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type)

I want to select one element depend of that TextBox text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, but it is not very good solution. It works for me and maybe it will help somebody.

I do it like that:

```
var listBoxItem = repairCompanyList.Find.AllByType<ListBoxItem>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Text == "Name");
Assert.IsNotNull(listBoxItem, "Lack of expected list box item");
listBoxItem.User.Click();
```

I checked